# Excel VBA to sum with dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a excel macro calculating a sum of values in Marks column using a certain dynamic range.

If total of subject marks contains 0, then it should give me sum of marks obtained in subjects.

[image]

This is code which I tried but that failed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, StartPoint As Long, EndPoint As Long

    StartPoint = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            If .Range("H" & i).Value = "??????? ?????" Then
                EndPoint = i - 1

                .Range("J" & i).Value = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(StartPoint, 2), .Cells(EndPoint, 2)))
                StartPoint = i + 1

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you identify the names that are to be selected? By color?

Comment: this is code which i tried but gives me output at last column

Comment: Sub Sum_Dyna_Rng()

    Dim lCell As Range

    Set lCell = Range("J9").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) ' find first blank cell at bottom of data

'Place the SUM formula into the last cell
    With Sheet1
         lCell.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Range("J9"), Range("J14").End(xlDown)))
    End With

End Sub

Comment: I added your code to your post... in the comments no one will see it. You can add other changes to your original post by using edit.

Comment: @rohrl77 see the last highlighted column which has 0, but the marks in subjects are there. I need sum of the marks if the total is 0 and if the marks are 0 in subjects then it must move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Sumif` function or the `Sumproduct` function.  Here are a couple of examples to get you going.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"Ford",C1:C10)

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Ford")*(B1:B10="June"))
```

See the link below for details.

http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html